# how to insert array of data per column in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I have arrays stacked in 1 array and I would like to insert each array per column in MySQL.
I have reached to insert all data in arrays to 1 column, but I want to insert an array per column.
Please see the screenshot and code below.

[Image of array stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi5iy.png)

```
con.connect(async(err)=>{
  const x = await getStock()
  if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return err;
  }else{
      console.log("DB ok");
  }
  console.log("connected");
  x.filter(item=>item===undefined?false:true).map(item=>item.forEach(item=>{
    const sql ="INSERT INTO test (testCol1) VALUES ?";
    const values=[
      [item]
    ];
    con.query(sql,[values],(err,result)=>{
      if(err)throw err;
      console.log("this have been recorded"+result);
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: Do you know beforehand how many columns you'll need? Or can the number of arrays change?

Comment: number of arrays are static, there are 6 arrays @JacoT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for this case.
It can be a little bit confusing but it is working.
Maybe there exists way easier and understandable solution, but this is the solution I have at the moment.

In the code above I was using only 1 array iterator, which was returning me an array. I decided to iterate the returned array to get each integer and insert data into MySQL, also the `(test${i+1})` sets array into necessary column.

```
  x.filter(item=>item===undefined?false:true).forEach((item,i)=>{
    item.forEach(item=>{
      const sql =`INSERT INTO test (test${i+1}) VALUES ?`;
      const values=[
        [item]
      ];
      con.query(sql,[values],(err,result)=>{
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log("this have been recorded"+result);
      });
    })
  });
```